# Proper NDK Setup

Tags: android, c++11, android-ndk

While working on a Android project, I got a little frustrated over how slow Java was at doing file operations. One or two files is fine, but reading a couple of 100 files at once takes a long time. So I decided to try with JNI/C++ instead, and used a day to read up on the language and a day more on the NDK setup, JNI and such.

At first everything worked fine. I created the C++ part that I needed and it reduced the time reading the files significantly. At the same time I finally got an excuse to learn C++, which has been on my to-do for a long time.

But when I started testing this on other devices, I ran into problems caused by lack of proper C++ library on some of them. So I altered my config to make a static build instead. But for some reason the c++_static would not build. It seamed to be a common issue, so I switched to using gnustl_static instead. It worked, until I did the last testing on the last devices, where it crashed with an UTF error using NewStringUTF. I searched around and found an advice about switching to stlport_static. This did fix the crash issue, but there was still a problem. I seamed to be missing some of the output on some devices.

I located this issue to my 'Set' container. No mater what I tried adding, it kept being empty on some of the devices, while working fine on others. If I switched to a 'Vector' container it worked fine on all devices.

My question here is, Android's NDK tool seams to be very unstable. I have 5 testing devices with different versions of Android, and even with a static build library in C++, it seams to be running very differently on each of them. Even if I get this working on all 5 devices, how can I be sure that an issues will not arise on a 6'th device that I cannot test on? I know that plenty of applications is build with C/C++ libraries attached to them, are these usually build width the NDK tools, or do people use 3'th party compilers and such to create these? I need to make some kind of setup that will works a bit more stable than this, but not sure how. I have been working with C++ and JNI for about 3 days total, so my experience in this area is not very large.

I have a Code::Block environment next to my Android/Eclipse setup, which I used to create some testing code while reading about C++. Using this on my regular Linux desktop works great. But can this be setup to work with Android's JNI?

**EDIT:**

IT seams that most of my latest problems is caused by character encoding issues. It seams that this is handled differently depending on the Android version.

For instance I parse a String array to C++ and extracts the data to std::string variables in a 'Set' container. For some reason I could not compare this to some values extracted from a bunch of files. It worked on some devices (KitKat and Lollipop), but not on a third (Jelly Bean 4.1). So I tried debugging this starting with parsing the file values back to Java in order to print them to the screen. This resulted in an error ***'illegal continuation byte 0x70'***, while converting it to Java Strings.

On the Android developer page, it is stated:

> Unless you know the data is 7-bit ASCII, you need to strip out
>   high-ASCII characters or convert them to proper Modified UTF-8 form

But I have no idea how this is done.

I tried printing the content from the files and then my parsed data from Java. The problem is the parsed data. ***GetStringUTFChars*** is returning something that cannot be correctly read properly by C++ when adding the value to an ***std::string*** variable. And something that cannot be converted back to java using ***NewStringUTF***.

Comment: I can agree that using the NDK is extremely painful, but I've not seen the stability problems you are speaking of.  We have a fairly large and complex voip app that runs on C and C++ libraries in the NDK.  For the majority of the phones it works well, there may be tweaks necessary on some, but it does run.  We do use a project called javacpp, which eases the pain of the JNI code, it is very nice.

Comment: The JavaCPP looks like something worth looking into. But you just use the compilers and such provided by the NDK? And without large issues? The size of my issues depends on which static implementation that I use, but none of them seams to work fully.

Comment: Yes, we use only the compiler supplied by the NDK.  We have tested on various arm, arm-v7a and x86 without issues.  I don't think we've run into any mips devices yet.  I cringe when I have to track down issues in the C code.  I'd avoid it all costs, IMO.  How are  you reading the files in Java that's it is too slow, and why so many files?

Comment: I have tried using every method for file reading in Java, it cannot beat C++ or even come close, when we are talking this amount of files at once. I am collecting various information about the current running processes. Depending on the information and the amount of processes, this is somewhere between 200-500 files. Often just a small part of a single line, but for each process.